# reldist::wtd.iqr gives different result from IQR for equal weights

Tags: r, statistics, iqr

I've been getting unexpected results using the `wtd.iqr` function from the `reldist` package (version 1.6.6) to calculate a weighted interquartile range (as opposed to the unweighted interquartile range returned by `IQR` from the vanilla R `stats` package). To explore the problem, I tried comparing the output of `reldist::wtd.iqr` to the output of `IQR`.

To my surprise, I found that `IQR` and `reldist::wtd.iqr` return completely different output values for the same input values *even when the input values are equally weighted* (i.e. when weighting should make no difference).

```
> x <- rnorm(10000)
> wt <- rep(1, length(x))
> paste(c('IQR:', IQR(x), 'wtd.iqr:', reldist::wtd.iqr(x, weight = wt)))
[1] "IQR:"              "1.34879539936654"  "wtd.iqr:"          "0.675866062623211"
>
```

In the above test, `IQR` seems always to return an output value approximately double the value that `wtd.iqr` returns for the same input values.

With input values that do not follow the above distribution, this relationship does not necessarily hold true: in fact, with real data, I sometimes get negative values from `wtd.iqr`, which I would have assumed to be impossible, but have never found that to happen with `IQR`.

In fact, it seems to me that `wtd.iqr` may actually be returning not the interquartile range but *one of the quartiles*. But if there's a bug here, it surely can't be such an obvious one --- can it?

Presumably the two functions define the concept of interquartile range in a different way, but there is no clue in the documentation. The documentation for `IQR` states that it 'computes interquartile range of the x values', while the documentation for `wtd.iqr` states that it 'Returns an empirical interquartile range from a weighted sample'.

Comment: Right, so this question has been downvoted. It would be nice if the person who did that could leave a comment to explain why.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The `iqr` and `wtd.iqr` function of the `reldist` package both have the same description. **Compute weighted Interquartile range (iqr)** and yes it's returning 25% which is quite strange.

Comment: Thanks, @TUSHAr. I've resorted to calculating the weighted iqr myself. But if it's a bug, it's such an obvious one that I'm surprised it slipped through... maybe I'm over-thinking it, though.

Comment: Good catch Westcroft_to_Apse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not overthinking. It's actually a bug. I have gone through the function definition here: https://github.com/cran/reldist/blob/master/R/wtd.quantile.R . It's using the `Hmisc` package's `wtd.quantile` function internally and then subtracting it with the probability values .25 and .75. But the two calls are being made in separate lines and hence R is treating it as different calls, rather than calculating the expression `a-b`, it returns `-b` which is the last line. Hence, -ve value of the 25% is being returned.

IF you simply try this:

```
quantile(x = x,c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))

#             0%                      25%                      50%                      75% 
#-3.903016136384592105202 -0.677263029412919159711 -0.012691140400805673433  0.636730086813689699632 
#                100% 
# 3.745404178709976328321 

reldist::wtd.iqr(x = x,weight = wt)

 #25% 
 #0.67726302941291915971
```

**The negative of 25%ile is returned. The last line is returned in an R function call.**

This is the function definition:

```
wtd.iqr <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, weight=FALSE) {
  wtd.quantile(x, q=0.75, na.rm = na.rm, weight=weight)
- wtd.quantile(x, q=0.25, na.rm = na.rm, weight=weight)
}
```

It should be:

```
wtd.iqr <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, weight=FALSE) {
  wtd.quantile(x, q=0.75, na.rm = na.rm, weight=weight) - wtd.quantile(x, q=0.25, na.rm = na.rm, weight=weight)
}
```

Comment: or one could put parentheses around the expression.  It would definitely be a good idea for someone to contact the maintainer (`maintainer("reldist")`)

Comment: @BenBolker I have dropped him a mail.